# Intepretation of Null Check Flutter Dart - What will this expression mean?

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I have a method to calculate location distance of items relative to two other references all of which have latitudes and longitudes. So we have three reference points: users home address, users current address and the items address.
Item Address: lat1, long1;
Users Home Address: lat2, long2
Users Current Location from GPS: lat3, long3
I have a method to calculate the distance taking in four parameters

```
calculateDistance(latA, longB, lat1, long1){//NOTE - lat1 and long1 must be provided from the db but latA and longB will be either of lat2 and long2 or lat2 and long2 OR default 0.12323 and 12.2343
}
```

I have to iterate through the lat1, long1, lat2, long2, to check the following: if lat1 and long1 or lat2 and long2 is null or empty then use default, if lat1 and long1 is null/empty and lat2 and long2 is not null/not empty then use lat2 and long2, if lat1 and long1 is not null/not empty and lat2 and long2 is null/is empty then use lat1 and long1. What is the simplest expression to evaluate and pass to the calculateDistance the values for the calculation. Can the tenary and null check expressions in Dart help, and how will they be written?
Please share your thoughts and expressions in Dart.

Answer (score 0):

Here You go

```
CalculateDistance(
    lat1,
    long1,
    lat3??lat2??0.12323,
    long3??long2??12.2343);
```

Or you could simply check this before passing to function. COmment if it doesnt works

Edited , Now it considers that lat1 and lat2 wont be null , and default value would be given if both 2&3 are null or 2 if 3 are null

Comment: calculateDistance(latA, longB, lat1, long1) //NOTE - lat1 and long1 must be provided from the db i.e. are not evaluted. So only latA and longB will be Either lat2 and long2 or lat2 and long2 OR default 0.12323 and 12.2343. Meaning, we can have the following possible expressions: calculateDistance(lat2, long2, lat1, long1) or calculateDistance(lat3, long3, lat1, long1) or calculateDistance(0.12323, 12.2343, lat1, long1) --- take note of the three possible values of the lat/long combination for only the first part. i.e. Your answer will not suffice @aman Verma

Comment: This would be simpler as `CalculateDistance(lat1 ?? 0.123323, long1 ?? 12.2343, lat2 ?? 0.12323, long2 ?? 12.2343)`.

Comment: @jamesdlin you are not condidering that it is either lat2 and long2 or lat2 adn long2 or 0.12323 and 12.2343 as the first values of the four needed for the calculateDistance. I am able to do an if/else (becomes long - thought of using tenary operators). the lat. and long are all doubles

Comment: I meant that using `??` would be simpler than the `== null ? ... : ...` checks in this partiular answer, not that `??` would solve what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

plz clarify if the 4 parameters are String or double. If they are double, then by empty do you mean 0.0 as the value?
Also your conditions are a bit unclear... They should be:

(lat1,long1) **AND** (lat2,long2) are null/empty - use default

(lat1,long1) - null/empty *AND* (lat2,long2) - not null/empty - use (lat2,long2)

(lat1,long1) - not null/empty *AND* (lat2,long2) - null/empty - use (lat1,long1)

(lat1,long1) - not null/empty *AND* (lat2,long2) - not null/empty - **then what?? use (lat1,long1)??**

I am ruling out the possibility of lat1 having a valid value, but long1 being null. Either both lat1 and long1 will be null/empty or both will have values.

Based on this you can either use a simple if/else or in an expression it would be something like so...

```
  lat1!=null ? calculateDistance(lat1, long1, latDB, longDB): lat2!=null? calculateDistance(lat2, long2, latDB, longDB): calculateDistance(0.12323, 12.2343, latDB, longDB);
```

Here I am considering that you will want to use lat1 and long1 if lat1 and lat2 both are not null.

However, such an expression leads to lack of readability of code and no performance gain. Hence it's much better to declare a separate function in which you can clearly show the if/else statements. Pass the values to it and call the calculateDistance() method inside it.

Comment: Condider that it is either lat2 and long2 or lat2 adn long2 or 0.12323 and 12.2343 as the first values of the four needed for the calculateDistance. I am able to do an if/else (becomes long - question is, this long if/else, can it be replaced with a short one using tenary operators). the lat. and long are all doubles

Comment: I dont understand your misprinting lat2 and long2 or lat2 and long2 or 0.12323 and 12.2343 , the first two choice are same , maybe you could try correcting same in question

Comment: @ombiro doesn't the expression that I have shared work for you?

Comment: Actually, we are kind of solving your requirement for you by analyzing the conditions for you. Instead in your question you should share the code - if-else statements that you have written and then ask how to make it more concise.

Comment: I will get back shortly, was in the middle of some debug on the same area ( i will test and give feedback please). thanks.